# How to use a class method in cupsEnumDests?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, cups

I am starting a program which will be using the CUPS C API, and the first example is calling the `cupsEnumDests` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cups/cups.h>

int print_dest(void *user_data, unsigned flags, cups_dest_t *dest)
{
  if (dest->instance)
    printf("%s/%s\n", dest->name, dest->instance);
  else
    puts(dest->name);

  return (1);
}

int main(void)
{
  cupsEnumDests(CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_NONE, 1000, NULL, 0, 0, print_dest, NULL);

  return (0);
}
```

But this function takes a C function as a parameter, while I am using C++ and I want to provide it a class method.

I tried `cupsEnumDests(CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_NONE, 1000, NULL, 0, 0, this->MyMethod, NULL);` but it gives the error

> error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int MyClass::MyMethod(void*, unsigned int, cups_dest_t*)’

**update** I found that it does work when I make the method `static`, but I would like to use `this->MyMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to convert a non-static class member function into a regular function pointer.  A common way to solve this, and your API allows it, is to pass a function pointer that takes a `void*` and then you pass in the optional data as a `void*` to the API function and then your function converts that `void*` to the class type and calls it's member function.

That would make your code look like

```
struct Foo
{
    void some_function() { /* do stuff */ }
};

int wrapper_func(void* instance, unsigned flags, cups_dest_t *dest)
{
    static_cast<Foo*>(instance)->some_function();
    return 42;
}

int main(void)
{
    Foo f;
    cupsEnumDests(CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_NONE, 1000, NULL, 0, 0, wrapper_func, &f);
}
```

Comment: That is what my solution became to be as well yes. Only I put the `wrapper_func` as a static method in the class (to keep everything together).

Comment: @BartFriederichs That works just as well.  Glad this helped you out.